# SageMath: How to extract the numerical value from a Modular pow

Tags: python, modulo, sage

In the sagemath command line, when I do an operation like this

```
sage: m = pow(2, 5, 2)
sage: m
0
sage: m = pow(2, 5, 3)
....: n = pow (3, 5, 4)
....: m
2
sage: n
3
sage: m * n

unsupported operand parent(s) for *: 'Ring of integers modulo 3' and 'Ring of integers modulo 4'
```

From this, it looks like whenever you call modular `pow`, then the output becomes associated with the modulus rather than being a numerical value in itself

This doesn't happen in a native python program though.

cat a.py

```
m = pow (2, 5, 3)
n = pow (3, 5, 4)
print (m*n)
```

python a.py

```
6
```

Also, if I multiply the numbers, the multiplication is also done modulo even if I have not asked it to be done so

```
sage: m = pow(2, 5, 5)
....: n = pow (3, 5, 5)
....: m
2
sage: n
3
sage: m * n
1
```

So my questions are

1. How do I extract a numerical value from `m` & `n` here, so that I can use them in non-modular operations?
2. Is this something specific to `pow`? If not, what other functions exhibit this behavior?
3. Is there any rationale behind this - I mean, python itself doesn't do this
4. Can it be turned off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid modular exponentiation giving "integers modulo something",
use `power_mod`:

```
sage: a = power_mod(2, 5, 3)
sage: b = power_mod(3, 5, 4)
sage: a, a.parent(), b, b.parent()
(2, Integer Ring, 3, Integer Ring)
sage: p = a * b
sage: p, p.parent()
(6, Integer Ring)
```

To rescue "integers modulo something" into "usual integers",
use `int` or `Integer` or `ZZ`:

```
sage: m = pow(2, 5, 3)
sage: n = pow(3, 5, 4)
sage: m, m.parent(), n, n.parent()
(2, Ring of integers modulo 3, 3, Ring of integers modulo 4)

sage: p = int(m) * int(n)
sage: p, type(p)
(6, <class 'int'>)

sage: p = Integer(m) * Integer(n)
sage: p, p.parent()
(6, Integer Ring)

sage: p = ZZ(m) * ZZ(n)
sage: p, p.parent()
(6, Integer Ring)
```

To check what the Sage preparser does in this case:

```
sage: preparse('m = pow(2, 5, 3)')
'm = pow(Integer(2), Integer(5), Integer(3))'
```

So Sage is not tweaking `pow` but merely turning
any integers in the input into Sage integers.
What happens then is that `pow(a, b, c)`
becomes `a.__pow__(b, c)` and Sage integers
have their own `__pow__` method that spits out
integers modulo something.

To turn off the Sage preparser:

```
sage: preparser(False)
sage: m = pow(2, 5, 3)
sage: n = pow(3, 5, 4)
sage: m, type(m), n, type(n)
(2, <class 'int'>, 3, <class 'int'>)
sage: p = m * n
sage: p, type(p)
(6, <class 'int'>)
```

To avoid the behaviour while using `pow` and with the preparser on,
mark integers as raw or use `int`:

```
sage: preparser(True)

sage: m = pow(2r, 5r, 3r)
sage: n = pow(3r, 5r, 4r)
sage: m, type(m), n, type(n)
(2, <class 'int'>, 3, <class 'int'>)
sage: p = m * n
sage: p, type(p)
(6, <class 'int'>)

sage: m = pow(int(2), int(5), int(3))
sage: n = pow(int(3), int(5), int(4))
sage: m, type(m), n, type(n)
(2, <class 'int'>, 3, <class 'int'>)
sage: p = m * n
sage: p, type(p)
(6, <class 'int'>)
```

To disable all conversions of Python ints to Sage integers
while keeping the Sage preparser on:

```
sage: Integer = int
sage: m = pow(2, 5, 3)
sage: n = pow(3, 5, 4)
sage: m, type(m), n, type(n)
(2, <class 'int'>, 3, <class 'int'>)
sage: p = m * n
sage: p, type(p)
(6, <class 'int'>)
```

To restore conversion of Python ints to Sage integers:

```
sage: Integer = sage.rings.integer.Integer
```